# My KeyStrokesCounter was working well until today

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developping a Dev StopWatch that have one executable for the key strokes counter and one for the main software neither m'y Key counter executable works in m'y main software project nor the standalone Key counter project..

Was working all fine yesterday but now it doesn't and I really don't know the reason.

It can't be because a recent windows update right ?

I've cleaned the project, make a scan , tried to comment unessesary part from  the code, it seems that he can detect m'y key when I remove m'y logic but it can't work properly without it, like I said it was working all fine yesterday.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using SlipegFramework;
namespace KeyStrokeCounter
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
        private static int Count = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //if (args[0] == "true")
            //{
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                    {
                        int KeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                        if (KeyState == 1 || KeyState == -32767) //Doesn't   detect anything
                        {
                           Count++;
                           Console.WriteLine(KeyState);//So don't print anything for debug.
                           Console.WriteLine(Count);
                           SlipegFramework.IO.WriteToBinary(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Strks.bin", Count); //You can ask for this code but it shoudn't be necessary
                       } 
                    }
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

only supposed to increment m'y Count variable and print it into the bin file using the BinaryWriter which is located in m'y personal tool.

I'm not english so sorry if there's anything unclear. thanks for any answer given.

EDIT1:
I've updated windows and i'm currently updating Visual Studio even if I don't believe he as something to do with it, and doing a system scan. This is so odd maybe it's my system, some sort of memory corruption?.

Or something is wrong with user32.dll ? i tried this code on a new project and it didn't change anything.

EDIT2:
Did some digging and had an idea, I openned my software into a vm and it work fine, but only in the vm so IT IS my system. how can i fix it ?

Anyone have an idea? I will try more tomorrow after a system restart.

Comment: If it’s not working, how can you tell? Is there an error or other expected behavior which is verifiable?

Comment: No error at all, the loop is working because the window doesn't close i'm juste really confused about the problem.

It work kind of, but not as expected

Comment: Is GetAsyncKeyState(i) returning what you expect? These are things that you should be able to debug pretty easily and narrow down the problem without our help

Comment: No it doesn't and I actually have some really weird behavior and the console stay blank, here is some output that i have when running the app in cmd as administrator without even touching any key:1
1
1
2
1
3
1
4
1
5
1
6
1
7
1
8
1
9
1
10
1
11
1
12
1
13
1
14
1
15
1
16

Comment: Like i said it was working fine yesterday and without doing anything it doesn't anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved, and this was caused by a recent windows 10 update, rolling back to a previous one fixed it.